# How can I combine the following MYSQL queries to achieve the anticipated results?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is my first query:

```
SELECT
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.user_login,
wp_users.user_email,
COUNT(CASE WHEN wp_posts.post_status IN ('draft', 'publish', 'private', 'future', 'pending', 'trash', 'auto-draft') THEN 1 END) AS total_lessons,
COUNT(CASE WHEN wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' THEN 1 END) AS published_lessons
FROM wp_posts, wp_users
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'sfwd-courses'
AND wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID
GROUP BY wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_nicename
ORDER BY total_lessons DESC, published_lessons DESC;
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

This is my second query:

```
SELECT
wp_users.user_login,
wp_users.user_email,
firstmeta.meta_value as first_name,
lastmeta.meta_value as last_name
FROM wp_users
left join wp_usermeta as firstmeta on wp_users.ID = firstmeta.user_id and firstmeta.meta_key = 'first_name'
left join wp_usermeta as lastmeta on wp_users.ID = lastmeta.user_id and lastmeta.meta_key = 'last_name'
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

I wanted to merge 2nd query with 1st one so I can get counts with first_name, and last_name. I'm looking for output something as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use subquery

```
SELECT
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.user_login,
wp_users.user_email, d.first_name, d.last_name,
COUNT(CASE WHEN wp_posts.post_status IN ('draft', 'publish', 'private', 'future', 'pending', 'trash', 'auto-draft') THEN 1 END) AS total_lessons,
COUNT(CASE WHEN wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' THEN 1 END) AS published_lessons
FROM wp_posts, wp_users, 
    (SELECT wp_users.ID,
    wp_users.user_login,
    wp_users.user_email,
    firstmeta.meta_value as first_name,
    lastmeta.meta_value as last_name
    FROM wp_users
    left join wp_usermeta as firstmeta on wp_users.ID = firstmeta.user_id and firstmeta.meta_key = 'first_name'
    left join wp_usermeta as lastmeta on wp_users.ID = lastmeta.user_id and lastmeta.meta_key = 'last_name') d

WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'sfwd-courses'
AND wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID
AND wp_users.ID = d.ID
GROUP BY wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_nicename
ORDER BY total_lessons DESC, published_lessons DESC;
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error

Error Code: 1055. Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'd.first_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: try updated query now, I was using my own prefix for the table